# Combining a group buy with a window function?

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to figure out how to combine a group by with a window function

I have field as

```
timestamp track_name
```

where timestamp represents the time the track was played.

If I want to get the track that was played most each day how can I do this?

I would need a **count of track_name grouped by date(timestamp), and track_name**

but not sure how to do that grouped by count and then get the most for that day?

thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly mix analytic functions with a `GROUP BY` query.  In the query below, I aggregate by date and track name, but also generate a rank based on the aggregated count.  For each date, the track having the highest rank is retained.  Note that I use `RANK` rather than `ROW_NUMBER`, since the former can handle the possibility of two or more tracks being tied for the most number of plays on a single day.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS dt, track_name,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(timestamp) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY DATE(timestamp), track_name
)

SELECT dt, track_name
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

This works because analytic functions are evaluated *after* `GROUP BY` has already finished.  So, the `COUNT(*)` is available to be used in the call to `RANK()`.

Comment: Thanks, if I didnt want to use the above as CTE, i can just use the actual select dt, track_name from ( inner query) where rnk = 1 correct? as a subquery?

Comment: @Chris90 Yes, you may just inline the CTE, i.e. do: `SELECT dt, track_name FROM (...CTE...) AS t WHERE rnk = 1`

Comment: Thanks, I was making it harder then it seems as I did not know how to use group by in the window function!

Comment: I noticed you deleted last comment, is there an issue with the answer?

Comment: No issue with the answer, you may wait for other answers if you still have other requirements.

Comment: if I want end result to be sorted by earliest day of month I can just add order by dt correct?

Comment: @Chris90 No, if you want to sort by _day_ of the month itself, then you should probably be using `ORDER BY DAY(dt)`.  If you want to sort by _date_, then just use `ORDER BY dt`.